# how to close angular filter in protractor

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, testing, protractor

I want to close the angular page filter text box. Close button will appear on Mouse over on text box. I want to click on close button through protractor with out mouse action.
I am trying to inject CSS style for close button was appear but unable to close.

Currently using bellow code:

```
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].style.opacity='1'",ClearFilterElement).then(function(){
    browser.executeScript('arguments[0].click()',ClearFilterElement);
});
```